# How to read a polynomial from a text file in Julia?

Tags: julia

I use the package TypedPolynomials and I want to read a polynomial from a text file. How can I do this?

If I use

```
julia> poly = read("test.txt", String)
```

this will give me a string. How can I convert it into a polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ideas.

You can do is `Meta.parse` and `eval` the `String` you read in. Note though that it is not a safe operation, so you should be sure what you read-in is actually safe to run (or someone might wipe your disk). Here is an example:

```
julia> @polyvar x
x

julia> p = eval(Meta.parse("3x+4x^2"))
4x² + 3x

julia> dump(p)
Polynomial{Int64,Term{Int64,Monomial{(x,),1}},Array{Term{Int64,Monomial{(x,),1}},1}}
  terms: Array{Term{Int64,Monomial{(x,),1}}}((2,))
    1: Term{Int64,Monomial{(x,),1}}
      coefficient: Int64 4
      monomial: Monomial{(x,),1}
        exponents: Tuple{Int64}
          1: Int64 2
    2: Term{Int64,Monomial{(x,),1}}
      coefficient: Int64 3
      monomial: Monomial{(x,),1}
        exponents: Tuple{Int64}
          1: Int64 1
```

Another option is to `include` the file:

```
julia> @polyvar x
x

julia> p = include("test.txt")
4x² + 3x

julia> dump(p)
Polynomial{Int64,Term{Int64,Monomial{(x,),1}},Array{Term{Int64,Monomial{(x,),1}},1}}
  terms: Array{Term{Int64,Monomial{(x,),1}}}((2,))
    1: Term{Int64,Monomial{(x,),1}}
      coefficient: Int64 4
      monomial: Monomial{(x,),1}
        exponents: Tuple{Int64}
          1: Int64 2
    2: Term{Int64,Monomial{(x,),1}}
      coefficient: Int64 3
      monomial: Monomial{(x,),1}
        exponents: Tuple{Int64}
          1: Int64 1
```

The same risks are associated with this method (the file can contain arbitrary Julia code).

If you wanted to be on the safe side probably you should check after `Meta.parse` step if the expression generated is actually a polynomial only.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `eval` and put previously known variables in local scope, as Bogumił Kamiński suggests, you can define your own parser and evaluator in a couple of lines -- polynomials are pretty simply, syntactically.  In [PEG.jl](https://github.com/wdebeaum/PEG.jl), one of the parser generators available in Julia, this could look like the following:

```
julia> function parse_polynomial(s)
           @rule variable = r"[a-z]"p |> (v -> Variable{Symbol(v)}())
           @rule number = r"\d+"p |> (digits -> parse(Int, digits))
           @rule optional_number = number[:?] |> (c -> isempty(c) ? 1 : c[1])
           @rule optional_exponent = (r"\^"p & number)[:?] |> (e -> isempty(e) ? 1 : e[1][2])
           @rule monomial = variable & optional_exponent > ^
           @rule term = optional_number & monomial > *, number
           @rule polynomial = r"\s*" & term & (r"\+"p & term)[*] > ((_, t, r) -> reduce((a, plusb) -> a + plusb[2], r, init = t))
           parse_whole(polynomial, s)
       end
parse_polynomial (generic function with 1 method)


julia> parse_polynomial(" 3x+4x^2 ")
4x² + 3x

julia> parse_polynomial("2 x + 1 x ^ 2+ 203")
x² + 2x + 203
```

I assumed `+` to be commutative here. Everything is packed into one function because I wrote the code in the REPL, but splitting it up would we advisible for actual usage.